# Why stream.parallel works slower than stream.sequential?

Tags: java

It looks like stream.parallel processing works slower than stream.sequential one - for the stream with a big amount of data. And speed of stream processing without explicit pointing the method is between sequential and parallel. Why?

```
package com.jsp;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test01 {
    enum Method {
        Default, Sequential, Parallel, SummaryStats
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long count = 30_000_000L;
        for (var method: Method.values()) {
            System.out.println(m + ": " + test(count, method));
        }
    }

    private static double test(long count, Method method) {
        // init stream with random values
        var r = new Random();
        Stream<Integer> s = Stream
                .iterate(r.nextInt(), prev -> r.nextInt())
                .limit(count);

        // estimate speed of processing method 
        var t1 = System.nanoTime();
        switch(method) {
            case Sequential -> s.sequential().reduce(Integer::max);
            case Parallel -> s.parallel().reduce(Integer::max);
            case SummaryStats -> s.mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
            default -> s.reduce(Integer::max);
        }
        var t2 = System.nanoTime() - t1;

        return (double) t2 / 1000000000;
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Default: 0.3314137
Sequential: 0.26828490
Parallel: 1.1365678
SummaryStats: 0.4159758
```

- HW: Huawei Matebook D14, AMD Ryzen 5 4500U, 8 Gb RAM
- SW: Windows 10 x64 22H2 Home Edition, Oracle OpenJDK 21

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- Random makes for non-reproducible and not identical tests
- Synchronization costs could be more expensive than doing things sequentially depending on what your task is